# DataZen - Data Connection cannot connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, datazen-server

I'm trying to create a data connection in DataZen to SQL Server 2014, but for any reasons it cannot connect.

My connection settings in SQL-Server:
[image: SQL Server 2014]

I want to connect to the adventureworks database in DataZen:
[image: Data Connection]

But every time I get the following error:
[image]

I am really desperate right now and appreciate every tip. I tried with "secure connection" and without, also with username and without.
The admin-user in DataZen is called "admin". But I don't think, that this makes any difference?!

Thank you very much!

Comment: are you connecting from the host where the SQL Server instance is running or across the network? Also, the first screenshot indicates you are logged into the machine as the local Administrator rather than a domain account. That might be causing Data Zen some grief. Check the make sure SQL Server has audit enabled for successful and failed logins then try connecting and see if anything pops up in the error log.

Answer (score 0):

- Put IP address of the server in **Data Source**
- Put Database name in    **Initial Catalog**
- Then specify the username and password(for connecting to DB)
- Test connection

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue-- the resolution was to add a new SQL login (in SSMS) with SQL Server authentication. Make sure to give this user appropriate permission on the tables you'll be working with in DataZen. Once I did that I was able to use that new login to successfully test the connection.